# How to see all options can be set for gragle.properties

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, kotlin-gradle-plugin

i haven seen many android samples and find that all uses mixtures of different options in `gradle.properties` and they have just given in docs like in these links

1. [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
2. [Kotlin code style](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/code-style-migration-guide.html#in-gradle)
3. [Kotlin kapt plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html#caching-for-annotation-processors-classloaders)
4. [Android X](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

but in docs they never really explain how to see and find all options that can be set and their default values

Answer (score 0):

There can be no complete list, because any plugin may use the `gradle.properties` file as its source for configuration. As shown in your first link, you may even define custom properties that can be used directly in the build script:

**gradle.properties**

```
junitVersion=4.13.2
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: junitVersion
}
```

Comment: not what i ask for i mean is there any commands to see the what configuration plugins add to be set in ths file or any other way to find we we can access source like in case of koltin kapt plugin is open source so what file is in which these configuration define